# ObservableCollection populated but will not show up in android display

Tags: android, observablecollection

I am fairly new at working with the Android code in Visual Studio 2019. The ultimate result desired here was to be able to display the various wifi Access Points near the phone.  I have gotten the wifi scan to work and I can see the results of the scan in the "WifiScans" collection but the listWifiScan ListView does not show the results on the display.  I can see lines on the display for the number of items that should be displayed.  If I touch one of the items I can see it turn to a solid color (Orange) but the information is not displayed.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks for any help you can give.

```
using Android;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Support.V4.Content;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;


namespace MobileWifi
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        ObservableCollection<WifiScan> WifiScans { get; set; }

        Label lblTitle;
        ListView listWifiScan;
        readonly Button btnWifiScan;
        public static bool response = false;

        public MainPage()
        {
            // add code to handle the components here
            WifiScans = new ObservableCollection<WifiScan>();
            this.Padding = new Thickness(20,20,20,20);    // wall padding for page

            // Listview data template
            var scanDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
            {
                var grid = new Grid();
                var bssidLabel = new Label { FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold };
                var ssidLabel = new Label();
                var levelLabel = new Label { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End };
                bssidLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "BSSID");
                ssidLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "SSID");
                levelLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Level");

                grid.Children.Add(bssidLabel);
                grid.Children.Add(ssidLabel, 1, 0);
                grid.Children.Add(levelLabel, 2, 0);

                return new ViewCell { View = grid };
            });
            
            // setup StackLayout for controls and set spacing of controls within the layout
            StackLayout panel = new StackLayout
            {
                Spacing = 15,
                Margin = new Thickness(20),
            };
            panel.Children.Add(lblTitle = new Label
            {
                Text = "Mobile Wifi Scanner",
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            });
            panel.Children.Add(btnWifiScan = new Button
            {
                Text = "Start Scan"
            });
            panel.Children.Add(listWifiScan = new ListView
            {
                ItemsSource = WifiScans,
                HasUnevenRows = true,
                ItemTemplate = scanDataTemplate,
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0),
            });


            btnWifiScan.Clicked += OnBtnWifiScanClicked;
            this.Content = panel;
        }

        private void OnBtnWifiScanClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            btnWifiScan.Text = "Scanning...";
            WifiScans.Clear();  // clear out results from previous scan

            try
            {
                IWifiScan service = DependencyService.Get<IWifiScan>().GetObj();
                service.Start();
                service.Finished += WifiScanDone;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                btnWifiScan.Text = "Start Scan";
                DisplayAlert("Alert", ex.Message, "OK");
            }
        }

        public void WifiScanDone(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            IWifiScan service = DependencyService.Get<IWifiScan>();
            List<string> WifiBSSID = service.GetBSSID();
            List<string> WifiSSID = service.GetSSID();
            List<int> WifiLevel = service.GetLevel();
            int count = WifiBSSID.Count;

            // add logic here to display the data from the scan
            // add results of the scan
            if(count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    WifiScans.Add(new WifiScan { WifiBSSID = WifiBSSID[i], WifiSSID = WifiSSID[i], WifiLevel = WifiLevel[i].ToString()});
                }
            }else
            {
                WifiScans.Add(new WifiScan { WifiBSSID = "None Found", WifiSSID = "", WifiLevel = "0"});
            }
            
            btnWifiScan.Text = "Start Scan";
            // finalize the scan, etc.
            service.Done();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem.  It turns out I did not specify the correct property in the binding.  The correct code for the binding in the data template should have been:

```
                bssidLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "WifiBSSID");
                ssidLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "WifiSSID");
                levelLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "WifiLevel");
```

I'm not sure where I got the original values but after studying the data binding properties I realized they were wrong.  Also I did not include the source in the original question that would have helped identify the problem so I am adding it here in case it is helpful to someone else that may have a similar problem.

```
    public class WifiScan
    {
        public string WifiSSID { get; set; }
        public string WifiBSSID { get; set; }
        public string WifiLevel { get; set; }

    }
```